# Recursive Steam API Call does not terminate

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, axios, steam-web-api

I am calling an API endpoint for one of Steam's games through their web api using axios and promises in Node.js. Each JSON response from the endpoint returns 100 match objects, of which only about 10 to 40 (on average) are of interest to my use case. Moreover, I have observed that the data tends to be repeated if called many times within, say, a split second.
What I am trying to achieve is get 100 `match_id`s (not whole match objects) that fit my criteria in an array by continuously (recursively) calling the api until I get 100 unique `match_id`s that serve my purpose.

I am aware that calling the endpoint within a loop is naive and it exceeds the call limits of 1 request per second set by their web api. This is why I've resorted to recursion to ensure that each promise is resolved and the array filled with `match_id`s before proceeding on. The issue I am having is, my code does not terminate and at each stage of the recursive calls, the values are the same (e.g. last match id, the actual built up array, etc.)

```
function makeRequestV2(matchesArray, lastId) {
  // base case
  if (matchesArray.length >= BATCH_SIZE) {
    console.log(matchesArray);
    return;
  }

  steamapi
    .getRawMatches(lastId)
    .then(response => {
      const matches = response.data.result.matches;

      // get the last id of fetched chunk (before filter)
      const lastIdFetched = matches[matches.length - 1].match_id;
      console.log(`The last Id fetched: ${lastIdFetched}`);

      let filteredMatches = matches
        .filter(m => m.lobby_type === 7)
        .map(x => x.match_id);

      // removing potential dups
      matchesArray = [...new Set([...matchesArray, ...filteredMatches])];

      // recursive api call
      makeRequestV2(matchesArray, lastIdFetched);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(
        "HTTP " + error.response.status + ": " + error.response.statusText
      );
    });
}

makeRequestV2(_matchIds);

// this function lies in a different file where the axios call happens
module.exports = {

getRawMatches: function(matchIdBefore) {
    console.log("getRawMatches() executing.");

    let getURL = `${url}${config.ENDPOINTS.GetMatchHistory}/v1`;
    let parameters = {
      params: {
        key: `${config.API_KEY}`,
        min_players: `${initialConfig.min_players}`,
        skill: `${initialConfig.skill}`
      }
    };

    if (matchIdBefore) {
      parameters.start_at_match_id = `${matchIdBefore}`;
    }

    console.log(`GET: ${getURL}`);
    return axios.get(getURL, parameters);
  }
}
```

I'm not exceeding the request limits and all that, but the same results keep coming up.

`BATCH_SIZE` is `100` and 
`_matchIds = []`

Comment: You need to return the promises, `return steamapi.getRawMatches(lastId)...` and `return makeRequestV2(matchesArray, lastIdFetched);`

Comment: @thefourtheye I've tried returning it but I'm still getting the same stuff. Is there a better way to achieve this? I'm happy to take suggestions. Long story short, I'm simply calling the api repeatedly (while staying within rate limits) and then stopping when i've reached a 100 items I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with replacing the line:

`matchesArray = [...new Set([...matchesArray, ...filteredMatches])];`

with this one:

`filteredMatches.filter(item => matchesArray.indexOf(item) === -1).forEach(item=>{
  matchesArray.push(item)
})`

What you were doing was that you effectively replaced the matchesArray var inside your function with new reference. I mean the var that you sent in function parameter from outside was no longer the same var inside the function. If you use matchesArray.push - you do not change the var reference though and the var in outer scope is accurately updated - just as is your intention.

This is the reason why `_matchIds` remains empty: each time there is a call to makeRequestV2, the inner variable `matchesArray` becomes 'detouched' from outer scope (during assignment statement execution) and although it gets populated, the outer scoped var still points to the original reference and stays untouched.

Comment: thanks for the response. I'll try it out some time soon. For now, I've resorted to using node cron to achieve some set interval in between calls, and it's working alright for me at the moment.